# Needs to convert CSS to SCSS in required format

Tags: css, sass

I Want to convert below mentioned CSS format to SCSS using variables or methods. Please suggest how to achieve.

CSS Format is:

```
.section-1-1{
 margin-left:0;
}
.section-1-1 + .section-1-2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.section-1-1 + .section-1-3 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.section-2-1{
 margin-left:0;
}
.section-2-1 + .section-2-2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.section-2-1 + .section-2-3 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Note: I may have to write more like .section-3-1, .section-4-1.... vice versa.

Comment: There are lots of tools online that do this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sass` you can clean up your code like this, no need to create variables.

```sass
.section-1-1 {
    margin-left: 0;
    + {
        .section-1-2 {
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
        .section-1-3 {
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
        .section-x { } ...
    }
}
.section-2-1 { .... }
```

If you have a lot of classes, you can create classes in a loop.

```sass
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  .section-#{$i}-1 {
      margin-left: 0px;
  }
  @for $j from 1 through 3 {
        .section-#{$i}-1 + .section-#{$i}-#{$j} {
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
  }
}
```

This will generate the following `CSS`.

```css
.section-1-1 {
     margin-left: 0px;
}
 .section-1-1 + .section-1-1 {
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .section-1-1 + .section-1-2 {
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .section-1-1 + .section-1-3 {
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .section-2-1 {
     margin-left: 0px;
}
 .section-2-1 + .section-2-1 {
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .section-2-1 + .section-2-2 {
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .section-2-1 + .section-2-3 {
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .section-3-1 {
     margin-left: 0px;
}
 .section-3-1 + .section-3-1 {
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .section-3-1 + .section-3-2 {
     margin-left: 15px;
}
 .section-3-1 + .section-3-3 {
     margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to SCSS converter: https://beautifytools.com/css-to-scss-converter.php

Here's the converter's output for your CSS:

```css
.section-1-1 {
    margin-left: 0;
    + {
        .section-1-2 {
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
        .section-1-3 {
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    }
}
.section-2-1 {
    margin-left: 0;
    + {
        .section-2-2 {
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
        .section-2-3 {
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
    }
}
```